# How to create a form and a table including editable fields on a single page in filament laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I am beginner to laravel filament. I want to make a form on a single page lets assume name is purchase-head and include data like supplier name invoice etc. Below form is a table which also acts like a form showing us column names like:
Product Name    Purchase Quantity   Unit Cost (Before Discount) Discount Percent    Unit Cost (Before Tax)  Line Total  Profit Margin % Unit Selling Price (Inc. tax)   Lot Number etc. i want to include values in this table from an other table say products.And after adding these products in these table we can edit these by directly editing the rows of table. i want to implement all this on a single page.

Comment: I think you're looking for the Repeater: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/repeater, there is also a plugin made called TableRepeater. An other option is to just use a relation manager: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/relation-managers#creating-a-relation-manager. With this you can add all relations possible to your form

Comment: Thanks bro i implemented that.